# Enquire.js and IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, enquire.js

I have this code that do not work on IE8... Googleing around I can not found a solution...

Do you know exactly how can I let it work on IE8 as well?

Here is the simple code (desktop, tablet and mobile are string variables with media queries...):

```
    enquire.register(desktop, {
                match: function () {
                    animate(a, b);
                }
            }).register(tablet, {
                match: function () {
                    animate(a, b);
                }
            }).register(mobile, {
                match: function () {
                    animate(a, b);
                }
            });

function animate(a, b) { ... };
```

Comment: maybe this help you: https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/issues/4

Comment: I had a look on it but I still do not understand how to let it work.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've tried adding the flag and the Paul Irish polyfill script before my EnquireJS script. No luck still. IE9 still doesn't adhere to the JS in the matched media query.

Answer (score 5):

It depends what you want to happen with IE8. If you just want it to run the desktop handler then alter your code as such:

```
enquire.register(desktop, {
  match: function () {
    animate(a, b);
  }
}, true) // note the true here
```

The `true` option, "shouldDegrade", tells enquire to treat the media query as always matching for incapable browsers (IE8 is incapable of CSS3 media queries). This is covered under the heading *"Mobile-First"* here http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/#delving-deeper

Alternatively, if you want full support for IE8 you'll have to use a more advanced `matchMedia` polyfill. Your options for polyfilling are covered here: http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/#legacy-browsers

Please read the documentation again, as you seem to have missed some important points :)